# PHP Invalid quoted-printable sequence, malformed q encoding from Yahoo

Tags: php, email, decoding, yahoo-mail

I came across the following error in PHP generated by an email forwarded from a Yahoo account:

> Notice: Unknown: Invalid quoted-printable sequence: =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off with Weekly Sale up to 90% off (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0

I've spent hours researching this issue and decided to send myself the exact same output string in an email without having Yahoo involved. The original q-encoded text that decodes correctly:

> =?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward=3A_Fw=3A_=F0=9F=98=89_A_great_Monday_kick-?= =?UTF-8?Q?off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90=25_off?=

The malformed q-encoded text from Yahoo:

> =?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?=

The correct string when decoded:

> GOG Forward: Fw:  A great Monday kick-off with Weekly Sale up to 90% off

Roundcube manages to decode both the normal and the malformed text though I'm not sure how and 25 *megabytes* is a bit much to dig through and I haven't been able to determine even where they're decoding subject headers.

How do I fix Yahoo's malformed version of q-encoding?

```
<?php
//These fail:
echo imap_mime_header_decode($mail_message_headers['Subject']);
echo quoted_printable_decode($mail_message_headers['Subject']);
?>
```

For clarification the [imap_fetchstructure](https://www.php.net/imap_fetchstructure) page clarifies the value `4` for encoding is `Quoted-Printable` / `ENCQUOTEDPRINTABLE`.

---

## New Development

It turns out that for some reason Yahoo sends the subject *twice* for the same header, one malformed and the other is not. Here is the `Subject` header from the *raw email*:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward:_Fw:_=F0=9F=98=89_A_great_Monday_ki?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: `quoted_printable_decode('=?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?=')` does work.

Comment: @Olivier That outputs `=?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?` which is incorrect.

Comment: As I understand, what you're trying to accomplish is 1) to be able to decode strings similar to `=?UTF-8?Q?...`? and 2) Being able to property import a message form yahoo?

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589910/fix-duplicate-ids-in-php-html-dom-to-be-converted-to-xml#comment114226738_64589910 looks interesting and clear to me, though I'm not a SME. I'd vote to reopen, you might ask in the PHP chat room if anything seems unclear about it, they might help too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a solution that uses Roundcube's source code to decode the message.

I posted the code and demo:

- [You can see it here](https://replit.com/@patricknomad/SarcasticCheerfulQuotient#main.php)
- Click the big play button to preview the extraction
- Go to code tab to see the extracted Roundcube code that you could use for your project

Since you mentioned to not use classes in the example I extracted Roundcube's `decode_mime_string()` function from [`rube_mime`](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_mime.php#L167), and a couple of things from [`rcube_charset`](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_charset.php) such as `$aliases`, `parse_charset()`, and `convert()`.

---

As far as decoding the malformed text from Yahoo:

> =?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?=

Into this:

> GOG Forward: Fw:  A great Monday kick-off with Weekly Sale up to 90% off

It's impossible. There's not enough data in there. For example it's missing the " A great Monday ki". Do you have the full source of the email address?

Comment: I can post the raw email headers if you'd like? Each email is just a file.

Comment: That would definitely help. Also possible to include the context of how you got this file?

Comment: I found the *raw email* and updated the bottom of my post. It turns out `mb_decode_mimeheader('=?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward:_Fw:_=F0=9F=98=89_A_great_Monday_ki?=')` works fine though how does Roundcube handle this oddity with two lines for the subject and discards the invalid line? WTF is wrong with the devs at Yahoo?

Comment: @John *"how does Roundcube handle this oddity"* This "oddity" is perfectly standard, as Patrick pointed out.

Comment: Patrick, good stuff! I can actually read your version of the code. I dumped the raw header as a fourth string and tested it out. It's ridiculous how much nonsense we have to deal with just to show a simple subject line. Thank you; accepted *and +1*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to go for any third party solution. There is already an in-built imap function for decoding strings like the one you given, i.e. `imap_utf8` and works pretty fine. Here's an example taken from your question.

```
<?php
    echo imap_utf8('=?UTF-8?Q?GOG_Forward:_Fw:_=F0=9F=98=89_A_great_Monday_ki?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?ck-off_with_Weekly_Sale_up_to_90%_off?=');
//GOG Forward: Fw:  A great Monday ki ck-off with Weekly Sale up to 90% off

?>
```

[image]

And as for your doubt why it was throwing that error for `quoted_printable_decode`, well actually your string is of type `utf8` encoded.